# extjs 5, Ext.view.View up() is undefined, why?

Tags: extjs, dataview

Ext.container.Container which itemid is 'imageContainer' contains a Ext.view.View and a Ext.form.Panel.
I define a itemclick in Container.

```
  ......
  listeners: {
    itemclick: 'showpic'
},

showpic: function(dataview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    console.log(dataview.up('imageContainer'));
    console.log(dataview.up('imageContainer').down('picform'));
 }
```

And it shows 'undefined' and a TypeError on console. how can i get picform and show that pic.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the '#', very silly, I should be more cautious.